# JSP Plain Text Email not rendering line breaks

Tags: jsp, email, outlook, line-breaks, plaintext

I have a contact form that, when submitted, posts all of the form's data into an email action, and then renders out a confirmation email in plain text.  The data is coming through just fine, but some of the lines are ignoring their respective line breaks.

**JSP:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/plain;" %><%@ page import="com.shared.Configuration" %><%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/jstl-core.tld" prefix="c" %>Contact Us Form: ${issue}

Name: ${name}
Email Address: ${emailAddress}
<c:if test="${not empty accessCode}">Access Code: ${accessCode}</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty itemId}">Inventory Number: ${itemId}</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty title}">Title: ${title}</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty device_active}">User Device: ${device}</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty os_active}">User Operating System/Version: ${operatingSystem}</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty browser_active}">User Web Browser/Version: ${webBrowser}</c:if>
<c:if test="${hasError eq 'Y' or hasError eq 'N'}"><c:choose><c:when test="${hasError eq 'Y'}">Error Message: ${errorMessage}</c:when><c:otherwise>No Error message was present</c:otherwise></c:choose></c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty otherDetails}">Other Details: ${otherDetails}</c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty problemDetails}">Problem Details: ${problemDetails}</c:if>**
```

As you can see, there are lots of IF Conditionals, basically, those are in place as a space saver, if the user didn't enter in any information in those fields, then don't put them in the email.

As it sits, Mac OS X Mail client, renders the email just fine, as does all web based clients. Outlook is the only one that is not playing nice, and renders out its emails as such:

**Outlook Email Result:**

```
Contact Us Form: Can't access the extra PlayBack+ features

Name: me
Email Address: jjozwowski@halleonard.com
Access Code: aqwsedrftgyhuj87
Inventory Number: 12345678
Title:Title: this track
User Device: Desktop
User Operating System/Version: Mac OS 10.9.5 User Web Browser/Version: Chrome 55 Error Message:
Other Details:no other details Problem Details:
```

The line breaks from User OS, User Browser, Error Message and Problem details are not in place.  No one in the office has a solution.  Anyone out there know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I would search for issues on three places:

1)

It could be an issue with the non-printable chars for new line in the JSP.

```
<c:if ...></c:if>\r\n
<c:if ...></c:if>\n
<c:if ...></c:if>\r
```

New line codes differ on the different OS:
Windows:`\r\n`.
Unix: `\n`
More info: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Look the not visible characters in your editor. For example in Notepad++ by clicking on ¶.
Unify it, if there are any differences.

2)

Check if the EL variables are containing newline characters their value.
This could be result of bad parsing or using not properly sanitized/trimmed strings.

How the EL are evaluated `${operatingSystem}`? `Mac OS 10.9.5\r`
Are there any new line characters?
If yes. trim the string before setting the variables.

3)

In combination with the previous 2 possibilities there is also possible that the trimDirectiveWhitespaces interferes.

Check if the deployment descriptor web.xml contains a block similiar to:

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

If the trimDirectiveWhitespaces is set to true, which makes sense for many cases, you can deactivate it for this particular case by adding to the JSP the line:

`<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="false"%>`

Look some example here:
[Remove Spacing between JSP variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003003/remove-spacing-between-jsp-variables/41006366#41006366)